# UIscrollview issue with iPhone X

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, xib

I am having a horizontal UIScrollview in my xib file. Scrollview looks great in all devices except iPhone X, XS and XR.

It looks good in iPhone 8

[image]

iPhone X

[image]

I have tried all the possible solutions,  Unchecked the under top bar, under bottom bar, auto resize subviews,nothing works for me. iPhone X always looks the same. Top constraint of the scrollview is set to safe area. I am using xib file here.

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
    } else {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.lectureTable.frame.size.width , height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Please shed some light. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself. Inside my scroll view, I have used UIView.

```
var hasTopNotch: Bool {
       if #available(iOS 11.0,  *) {
           return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 > 20
       }
       return false
   }

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    var topbarHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
    }
    if hasTopNotch{
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
            self.customView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (topbarHeight + topPadding!)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

    }else{
        let NavBarHeight  = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        self.customView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - NavBarHeight
    }


    }
```

This works great in all the devices.